# Should I copy six.py into my project or I can add it into setup requires instead?

Tags: python, six

Are there any pros and cons of contributing six
library together with my project code base or I can use it as a
regular python dependency?

Comment: Since it's not a standard Python library module, you should add it to your project code.

Comment: @martineau but it's available on pypi, why it's not a standard library?

Comment: How should I know? Anyway, I may have misunderstood your question.

Comment: @martineau what kind of `six.py` behaviour makes it differs from regular python code available on pypi?

Comment: Nothing that I know of. By "not a standard Python library module" I only meant not included with Python itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use it as a regular python dependency. [Here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dateutil/dateutil/trunk/view/head:/setup.py) is an example for the case.